# dateTimePicker C++

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Необходимо получить дату, выбранную пользователем с помощью компонента dateTimePicker (C++, VisualStudio 2010)... Вот мои попытки на данный момент:

```
  String^stra = dateTimePicker1->Date; //error C2039: 'Date' : is not a member of 'System::Windows::Forms::DateTimePicker'

  String^stra =  dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"); //  error C2228: left of '.ToString' must have class/struct/union
```

Comment: Помогаю: не пишите приложения с GUI на C++/CLI.

Comment: Для доступа к членам экземпляров по ссылке используйте `->` вместо точки: `dateTimePicker1->Value` - это и будет выбранная дата.